# Layout with VideoView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android dev and migrating Win app to Android, created a new project and faced a problem. Tha last LinearLayout with TextView doesn't have space to be displayed, what is wrong? In my case I need a top and bottom and ListView with VideoView should take all free space.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background = "@drawable/background">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:fontFamily="Arial"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvMain"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/myVideo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:fontFamily="Arial"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use weight attribute http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight. But normally you must not use nested layouts. You can try RelativeLayout instead

Comment: thank you, weight is a solution